# The logos in Titus 2:5

Tags: pauline-epistles, marriage, titus, logos

Titus 2:5 ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=titus%202%3A5&version=ESV)),

5 to be self-controlled, pure, working at home, kind, and submissive to their own husbands, that **the word of God** may not be reviled.

The Greek text of the phrase emboldened above is ὁ λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ (*ho logos tou Theou*).

Is the use of ὁ λόγος (*ho logos*) here to be understood as personalized in the same way ὁ λόγος (*ho logos*) is in the Gospel of John's [Prologue](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%201%3A1-18&version=ESV) (See also, [Revelation 19:13](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2019%3A13&version=ESV)). Said another way, is the λόγος (*logos*) here in Titus 2:5 the λόγος (*logos*) that was made flesh per John 1:14, or is this use of ὁ λόγος (*ho logos*) impersonal, and referring to something else, say, for example, the Scriptures, or even, something else?

Answer (score 4):

The phrase Ὁ Λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ occurs about 42 times in the NT.  In every instance except one (Rev 19:13) it refers to the written and spoken teaching about God, much as our modern technical term, "theology" (from the same phrase) does.  Here is a sample:

- Matt 15:6 - he need not honor his father or mother with it. Thus you nullify **the word of God** for the sake of your tradition.
- Mark 7:13 - Thus you nullify **the word of God** by the tradition you have handed down. And you do so in many such matters.”
- Luke 5:1 - On one occasion, while Jesus was standing by the Lake of Gennesaret with the crowd pressing in on Him to hear the word of God,
- Luke 8:1 - Now this is the meaning of the parable: The seed is the word of God.

This phrase does NOT occur in John 1 but first appears in his gospel in John 10:35, "If he called them gods to whom **the word of God** came—and Scripture cannot be broken"

**Rev 19:13**

The reason that Rev 19:13 is an exception to the above rule is rather simple - the text explicitly says the NAME of the rider on the white horse is "The Word of God" and thus is an allusion to John 1:1-3, 14.

**CONCLUSION**

Therefore, Titus 2:5 having "The word of God" is a reference to the written and spoken/preached teachings about God and Jesus.

Comment: +1 good answer.  "The term Λογος [Logos] is applied to Christ only in John 1:1, 14 and Rev. 19:13 and 1 John 1:1 ... a possible personification of “the Word of God” in Heb. 4:12. But the personal pre-existence of Christ is taught by Paul (2 Cor. 8:9; Phil. 2:6f.; Col. 1:17) and in Heb. 1:2f. and in John 17:5. This term suits John’s purpose better than σοφια [sophia] (wisdom) and is his answer to the Gnostics.... " 
 - - 
Robertson, A. T. Word Pictures in the New Testament (Jn 1:1).

Comment: Up-voted +1. Is there a list of the 42 occasions of Ὁ Λόγος τοῦ Θεοῦ ? I would be interested to possess such a list.

Comment: @NigelJ - I looked at the list in my GNT concordance which lists them.  However, if you do not possess such a concordance, I will list in an appendix for you.

Comment: @Dottard Appreciated. Thank you, but I shall be OK as I have just found that the listing of 'word' in Strongs is so clear that I can pick out the phrase without too much trouble. Regards.